# Math software to calculate in different rings.

Tags: math-software, computer-algebra-systems

I was doing computational experiment by using rings of polynomial like this

> let $f(x)=x^6+x\in\mathbb{Z_n[x]}$ for any given $n$.

Is there any software which help me to calculate $f(a)$ where $a\in\mathbb{Z_n}$.

Thanks!

Comment: I think a lot (if not all) programming languages have a "modulo" command, with which you can easily program this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: Have you tried Macaulay2? http://habanero.math.cornell.edu:3690/

Comment: And if a language doesn't have a "modulo" command built it, one can easily program a subroutine or function or method etc. to achieve the desired effect, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many computer algebra systems are capable of such computation. I mainly deal with GAP (http://www.gap-system.org), where you can do this, for example, in a very simple way like this:

```
gap> x:=Indeterminate(Rationals,"x");
x
gap> f:=x^6+x;
x^6+x
gap> Value(f,11);
1771572
gap> Value(f,11) mod 19;
12
```

just to create a polynomial with rational coefficients and then calculate a remainder using `mod`. Note that here $12$ is in $\mathbb{Z}$, not in $\mathbb{Z_n}$.

On this way, one should know the function `PowerModInt( r, e, m )` which returns `r^e mod m` for integers `r`, `e` and `m` (`e` non-negative): compare the runtime in the brute-force calculation

```
gap> 111122^131113345 mod 139; time;
2
33203
```

which takes about 33 seconds, with the instantly returned result of `PowerModInt`:

```
gap> PowerModInt(111122,131113345,139); time;
2
0
```

This happens because `PowerModInt` can reduce intermediate results and thus will generally be faster than using `r^e mod m`, which would compute `r^e` first and reduce the result afterwards.

A more "algebraically clean" approach could be to create a proper ring $\mathbb{Z_n}$ using `Integers mod n`, so that both $a$ and $f(a)$ will belong to $\mathbb{Z_n}$, for example:

```
gap> z42:=Integers mod 42;
(Integers mod 42)
gap> x:=Indeterminate(z42,"x");
x
gap> f:=x^6+x;
x^6+x
gap> a:=Random(z42);
ZmodnZObj( 2, 42 )
gap> Value(f,a);
ZmodnZObj( 24, 42 )
```

This corresponds to the fact that `(2^6+2) mod 42 = 2`.

It depends on the circumstances of the experiment whether to use one approach or another, or to use GAP or another system, such as for example [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) (see also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261000/differences-between-gap-and-pari-gp)).

**Remark:** note the usage of parentheses because of the rules of precedence of `mod` in GAP: compare

```
gap> (2^6+2) mod 42;
24
```

with

```
gap> 2^6+2 mod 42;
66
```

because the latter is equivalent to `2^6 + (2 mod 42)`.